# tomcat7.0.53 users authorization?

Tags: tomcat7

I've installed Tomcat 7.0.53 but while running, it says I'm not authorized. Then I changed Tomcat-users.xml and put in the roles and correct password, but when I open the localhost and try to login, it still shows "Not authorized". Please help me sort this out.

Tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager,admin,standard"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager,admin,standard"/>
```

While logging:

```
401 Unauthorized

You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
```

Comment: Yelling won't get you an answer any faster, nor will it get you a better answer. Keep the capslock down, please.

Comment: ohh sorry for that... i thought it is not visible... shall i change the whole content once again.. ?

Comment: No need, I edited it for you. You can edit it further if you'd like, but I don't think that's necessary unless you have more information you'd like to add. Just for future reference, when you hit the "Post Your Question" button the question does become public.

Comment: so ... do you have any solution... i searched every sites regarding this issue... but nothing it altered..

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I'm not a Tomcat user so I have no idea how to fix your problem. I just dropped in to fix your post's formatting. Best of luck finding an answer, though!

Comment: ohh ... took a while to find out... j2ee was corrupted.. so i fixed it now .. :)